# Deriving Show Instance for ADT not working with Higher Kinded Type Families

Tags: haskell, types

I was just working through Chris Done's ADT with default example [gist available here](https://gist.github.com/chrisdone/7dddadd089e6a5d2e3e9445c4692d2c2) and ran into a problem: my ADT, with fields defined by higher kinded type families, is not working with a deriving show instance. GHC is telling me I need to derive a Show instance for a Type Family, but I'm not sure how to do. Here's what I have, so far, any comments would be helpful.

In the following example (using **ghc 8.8.1**), the objective is to define an instance of `Show` for `ShowMe`, using derive if possible.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PartialTypeSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}

data Tag = A | B deriving (Show)

type family TF (p :: Tag) a where
  TF 'A a = ()
  TF 'B a = a

data ShowMe p = ShowMe
  { a :: !(TF p String)
  , b :: String
  }

main =  connect showMeDefaults { a = "some string" }
   where
     connect :: ShowMe B -> IO ()
     connect _ = pure ()
     showMeDefaults :: ShowMe A
     showMeDefaults = ShowMe { a = (), b = "asdf" }

-- This works to define Show
{-
instance Show (ShowMe p) where
  show _ = "hello"
-}
-- This instance is the line that causes an error
deriving instance Show (ShowMe p)
```

Subsequently, I'm getting an error that I'm not familiar with from GHC:

```
show_tf.hs:35:1: error:
    • No instance for (Show (TF p String))
        arising from a use of ‘showsPrec’
    • In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘(showsPrec 0 b1)’
      In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely
        ‘((.)
            (showsPrec 0 b1)
            ((.)
               GHC.Show.showCommaSpace
               ((.)
                  (showString "b = ") ((.) (showsPrec 0 b2) (showString "}")))))’
      In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely
        ‘((.)
            (showString "a = ")
            ((.)
               (showsPrec 0 b1)
               ((.)
                  GHC.Show.showCommaSpace
                  ((.)
                     (showString "b = ") ((.) (showsPrec 0 b2) (showString "}"))))))’
      When typechecking the code for ‘showsPrec’
        in a derived instance for ‘Show (ShowMe p)’:
        To see the code I am typechecking, use -ddump-deriv
   |
35 | deriving instance Show (ShowMe p)
```

If we recompile, using the `ghc -ddump-deriv`, the following is returned:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( show_tf.hs, show_tf.o )

==================== Derived instances ====================
Derived class instances:
  instance GHC.Show.Show Main.Tag where
    GHC.Show.showsPrec _ Main.A = GHC.Show.showString "A"
    GHC.Show.showsPrec _ Main.B = GHC.Show.showString "B"


Derived type family instances:



==================== Filling in method body ====================
GHC.Show.Show [Main.Tag]
  GHC.Show.show = GHC.Show.$dmshow @(Main.Tag)



==================== Filling in method body ====================
GHC.Show.Show [Main.Tag]
  GHC.Show.showList = GHC.Show.$dmshowList @(Main.Tag)


Linking show_tf ...
```

Conceptually, I think what I should be able to derive a Show instance for `TF`, but when I do that, I get the following:

```
show_tf.hs:36:31: error:
    • Illegal type synonym family application ‘TF 'A a’ in instance:
        Show (TF 'A a)
    • In the stand-alone deriving instance for
        ‘(Show a) => Show (TF 'A a)’

   |
36 | deriving instance (Show a) => Show (TF 'A a)
```

This error also appears if I just try to define the Show instance myself for `TF 'A a`. I've searched "Illegal type synonym", and haven't come up up with a way around this.

Comment: Excellent question! Was running into similar problem. Made my day brighter!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
```

and then suggest the wanted context to GHC:

```
deriving instance Show (TF p String) => Show (ShowMe p)
```

GHC won't add that context automatically since it can be surprising to the programmer.

Comment: Why can `Show` instances not be written for `TF`, and, further, why are they unnecessary?

Comment: @HTNW Instances must be associated to a type constructor to allow instance resolution. `TF` is a type family, and is disallowed. Indeed, we can not really expect GHC to solve a basic constraint like `C T` by observing that `T = F (some complex type)` and then realizing it can use the instance for type family `F` -- that would require too magic to solve undecidable problems. They are not nececessary in this case since in `TF p String` we have that `p` is `'A` or `'B`, so `TF p String` is either `()` or `String`. (We might need a singleton to prove `p` is such later on.)

Comment: Thank you! I understand that the `TF p String` is represented as `a` or `()` after type family application, but what's the reasoning behind adding the constraint `Show (TF p String)` ? Are type families not yet applied when type checking if `ShowMe` is a valid instance of Show?

Comment: @wespiserA GHC is not so powerful to make the reasoning step "`TF p String` is either this or that, and in both cases we have `Show`, so we can assume `Show`". One of the reason which prevents that is that at runtime `p` is not known (types are erased for efficiency) so it can not be tested, hence GHC has to know during compilation which `Show` instance to use. Passing a context tells GHC to use that instance.

Comment: @wespiserA This is related to the fact that we can't define `whichOne :: forall p . Either (p :~: 'A) (p :~: 'B)` which would prove that `p` is either `A` or `B`. We could do that in dependently typed languages like Agda or Coq, but in Haskell we can't due to type erasure. Worse, Haskell allows `type family G t :: Tag` without any defining equations, causing `G Bool :: Tag` even if that can not be reduced to either `A` or `B` -- a sort of "unspecified tag constant". This of course makes handling `TF (G Bool) String` impossible, since we can't simplify that type.

Comment: This is a nice solution. But want to chime in with a more brute-force alternative. Given this is a closed type family, can just enumerate for all the closed types, like `deriving instance Show (ShowMe 'A)` and similar for `'B`. Not nice, but works for a small number of types.